# Read/Set HTML of a Table Cell

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML code

```
<td id="td_ccs[79]" class="right">                                                                              <a id="btn_c[79]" class="button" name="ccs_button" rel="yes">YES</a>
</td>
```

I am simply trying to use jquery to read and rewrite the link in the cell. This is what I have

```
alert($('#td_ccs[79]').html());
$('#td_ccs[79]').html('new html code'))
```

But it keeps telling me my cell is null. Is this because its a table and not a div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [**Selectors Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

So use

```
 alert($('#td_ccs\\[79\\]').html());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPr3k/)

To Escape you can create a function and use it like

```
var escapeMetaChars = function (text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
alert($('#' + escapeMetaChars('td_ccs[79]')).html());
```

[**DEMO with escape function**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPr3k/1/)

Comment: Yes both methods worked, but I am actually getting that dynamically and just doing a .replace() to swap out the td_ is there a way to encode like encodeURI()?

Comment: @user3167249, sorry mate I am not getting you about *encode like encodeURI()*

Comment: is there a command to automatically encode all the meta-characters in a string? Or do I simply have to create my own function that loops through all of them and add "\\". (If I wanted a way to encode repeatedly)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the square brackets, since they're normally used to specify attribute selectors.

```
alert($('#td_ccs\\[79\\]').html());
```

Comment: So this does work? Tested it, but didn't seem like it. Edit: So Satpal brought the anwser...